# Page does not update after navigator.geolocation call in Rails (Check-in / Check-out functions)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using standard HTML5 location services. A user comes into a cafe, opens the app, clicks on "Check-in!" and the app gets the location and uses it until the user later clicks "Check-out!".

In my viewer, I call on a script containing navigator.geolocation and it does its job. I successfully pass the latitude and longitude parameters to my controller and it updates everything. But when all is done and I redirect_to root_url, the new page does not refresh (I know at some point I should do it more elegantly and just update the link part, but for now, I just want to get this going and understand what is going on). Here is my code:

In my viewer-

```
 <% if (@voterinfo.checkin == 0) %>
              <li>
                <h4>    <%= link_to "-->Check-In!", "#", :id => 'findMe' %>      </h4>
                <script>
                  $(function(){
                     $("a#findMe").click(function(){
                         if (navigator.geolocation) {
                             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                                 $.post('/users/set_geolocation/', {latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                                             longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                                             dataType: 'float'});
                             }, function () {
                                 alert('We couldn\'t find your position.');
                             });
                         } else {
                             alert('Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
                         }
                      });
                  })
                </script>
               </li>
          <% else %>
              <li> <h4><%= link_to "--->CHECK-OUT!", :controller => :users,
                                   :method => :set_geolocation %></h4></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
  <% end %>
```

And here is the relevant part of my users_controller-

```
 def set_geolocation
  @user = current_user
  @voterinfo = Voterinfo.find_by_user_id(@user.id)
  if (@voterinfo.checkin == 0)
    @user.update_attributes(:longitude => params['longitude'], :latitude => params[:latitude])
    @user.save(validate: false)
    sign_in(@user)
    @voterinfo.checkin = 1
    @voterinfo.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else
   @voterinfo.checkin = 0
   @voterinfo.save
   redirect_to root_url
  end
```

end

Thank you for any help here.

Comment: _“But when all is done and I redirect_to root_url, the new page does not refresh”_ – so most likely a simple caching problem; so apply a common “cache busting” technique when making that redirect.